# How to find type by inherited type parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection

i've got lots of classes inheriting from base classes but with different parameters like:

```
public class Model1(Provider provider)
   : BaseModel(provider, id: "model-1");

public class Model2(Provider provider)
   : BaseModel(provider, id: "model-2");
```

now i need to get the type by the 'id'.  assuming i have all my types from my assembly.  how do i do this?  for example, if i pass 'model-1', i should get back 'Model1' or the full namespace.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's impossible (at least with a "normal" reflection). You can access the `base` constructor parameters from the `Type` object.

Comment: Related https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/discussions/789

Comment: Can you add attributes to your classes with the "model" value? Then the constructor can extract the model name from the attribute to avoid the copy-paste (or just use the one constant in both attribute and consturctor)

Comment: These ids are variable, think about `class Model3(Provider provider, string id) :BaseModel(provider, id: id);` And also they belong to instances.